# how to fix error "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" at R?

Tags: r, if-statement, error-handling

my code :

```
for(k in 1:length(dat)){
   if(dat==boxplot(dat)$out[k]){
      dat<-NA
   }
}
```

and the result is

```
Error in if (dat == boxplot(dat)$out[k]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

how to fix it?

Comment: could we have a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) please ... ?  (The number of ways that `dat` is being used in this small code chunk makes me really nervous!)

Comment: precede it with `length(boxplot(dat)$out ) &`. If it's not there the first FALSE in a series of conjunctions will create a FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Could do one of two things; Fix the specific error

```
for(k in 1:length(dat)){
        if(length(boxplot(dat)$out ) & dat==boxplot(dat)$out[k]){
          dat<-NA
        }
      }
```

But that's really clunky R code. Better might be:

```
dat[ dat %in% boxplot(dat)$out ] <- NA
```

(It is, however, statistical malpractice to remove outliers.)

Comment: sorry, what is "statistical malpractice"?

Comment: Intentional distortion of data to fit preconceived notions of statistical "normality".